# Spherical polars normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I don't follow the part highlighted ingreen i.e why is $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sphere, the outward normal direction is exactly the radial direction.  More specifically, if 
$$S(x,y,z) = \langle r\cos \phi \cos \theta, r \cos \phi \sin \theta, r\sin \phi\rangle,$$ 
then $\|S\| = r$ and 
$$\vec{n} = \frac{S}{\|S\|} = \langle \cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi\rangle = \langle x_r , y_r, z_r\rangle.$$
So
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n} & = \nabla \Phi \cdot \vec{n} \\
& = \Phi_x x_r+\Phi_y y_r + \Phi_zz_r\\ & = \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r}.
\end{align*}